# Draw in composite

Tags: java, graphics, swt, composite

I have a Composite called Workspace. In this composite I want to add some graphics object. Each object can be selected, dragged, moved and can have complicated shape (circle, ellipse, polygon,...). I can click at each object to see its properties. What is the best way to implement?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: You can look at GEF : http://www.eclipse.org/gef/gef_mvc/index.php

Comment: @VincentRamdhanie am considering two ways of implementation: The first way is drawing everything in the workspace, and then handle events all in the workspace. The second way is creating event handlers for each graphics object. The second way seems much more better, but I still don't figure out how to create a flexible object like that

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [`Zest`](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseZest/article.html). [Here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseZest/article.html) is a very good tutorial for using Zest.

As an alternative, there is [`Draw2d`](http://www.eclipse.org/gef/draw2d/index.php). And again, [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/SWTDraw2D.htm) is a nice simple example:

[image]